# How to compare values from current and previous rows based on other values in data frame without loops in R

Tags: r

I have a log file converted to data frame with data like this:

```
Client  Date    Group   Count   Test
C1  1.437512e+12    6   2   0
C1  1.437685e+12    3   1   0
C2  1.437685e+12    3   1   0
C2  1.437772e+12    6   1   0
C2  1.438117e+12    6   2   0
C2  1.464037e+12    3   3   0
C3  1.448662e+12    6   2   0
C3  1.451081e+12    3   5   0
C4  1.437944e+12    6   1   0
C4  1.438895e+12    3   6   0
C5  1.460581e+12    3   2   0
C5  1.460668e+12    6   2   0
C5  1.460927e+12    6   1   0
C5  1.461013e+12    3   2   0
C6  1.437685e+12    3   1   0
C6  1.437944e+12    6   1   0
C6  1.447711e+12    3   2   0
C6  1.458079e+12    3   2   0
C7  1.463000e+12    3   5   0
C7  1.463000e+12    10  1   0
C8  1.463951e+12    6   5   0
C8  1.463951e+12    3   1   0
C9  1.463346e+12    3   5   0
C9  1.464037e+12    10  1   0
C10 1.459804e+12    3   2   0
C10 1.461272e+12    3   1   0
C10 1.461877e+12    5   1   0
C10 1.462223e+12    5   1   0
C10 1.462482e+12    5   1   0
```

Client is ID of a person in data base. Group is a category of this person in a current moment of time (rows are ordered from latest to newest). Count is a count of events made by a user in that day. Test is a column that I want to fill with values.

My main goal is to get for every user only those rows form this data frame, that has Group=3 before its' first change to some number, that is not equal to 3. I want to mark this rows in Test column and then sum Count values of this rows by each user.

I try to solve this problem with a for loop:

```
for (i in 2:length(log$Group)){
 if (log$Client[i-1] == log$Client[i]) {
  if ((log$Group[i-1] == 3) & (log$Group[i] != 3)) {
   log$Test[i] <- NA
  }
  if ((log$Group[i-1] != 3) & (log$Group[i] == 3)) {
   log$Test[i] <- NA
  }
  if ((log$Group[i-1] == 3) & (log$Group[i] == 3)) {
   if(is.na(log$Test[i-1])) {
    log$Test[i] <- NA
   }
  }
  if ((log$Group[i-1] != 3) & (log$Group[i] != 3)) {
   log$Test[i] <- NA
   log$Test[i-1] <- NA
  }
 }
}
```

But it take ages to run this loop on full data. Then I'll just delete all rows with NAs.

The result will be like this:

```
Client  Date    Group   Count   Test
C2  1.437685e+12    3   1   1
C5  1.460581e+12    3   2   1
C6  1.437685e+12    3   1   1
C7  1.463000e+12    3   5   1
C9  1.463346e+12    3   5   1
C10 1.459804e+12    3   2   1
C10 1.461272e+12    3   1   1
```

Is there any way to do all of this without loops? Or maybe is there better way to solve entire problem?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. As it stands, your code looks to see if the email value is the same as the previous row's, and then sets the value of test to NA if that row or the one before it is equal to 3. This doesn't sound like your description, though.

Comment: I've added another version of code. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly (and it is very difficult to understand), you should do something like the following (using package `dplyr`):

```
eventsToAnalyze %>%
    filter(group == 3) %>%
    group_by(client) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(Count))
```

This will filter out the rows not in group 3 and sum the values in the `Count` column by client.

**EDIT**

Ah, now that you've clarified your question, I see the problem. This should work if 3 is the lowest value:

```
eventsToAnalyze %>%
    group_by(client) %>%
    filter(cummax(group) <= 3) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(Count))
```

Otherwise you can use the messier but more general:

```
eventsToAnalyze %>%
    group_by(client) %>%
    filter(cummax(abs(group - 3)) <= 0) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(Count))
```

Comment: Or you could group by `group` and `client`, summarize, and then filter. That way you have the option of looking at other `group`s

Comment: Please, look at client C8. The event with group=3 for this client happened after the event with group=6. But I need to sum only those events with group=3, that happened earlier than events with other group for current client. So for client C8 there will be no such events.

Comment: I've just edited the answer above; I believe this is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect for me. I should spend more time on dplyr.